# How to create a method in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, methods

I am new at MySQL and wanted to know : how to create a method?

Comment: Do you mean a stored procedure?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? There are stored procedures and user-defined functions in MySQL. If we know what you're trying to do, we can provide more relevant advice.

Answer (score 2):

A stored procedure or function may be as close as you'll get. See: [CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean "method" in an object-oriented context?  If so, then SQL isn't really an object-oriented language; it's structured very simply around retrieving and doing (basic) manipulations of data in a database.

Comment: It's entirely absolutely _not_ an object-oriented programming language. It's not even a programming language, but a _query language_. Completely different kettle of fish. As goes the OP, I smell someone having been trained by some school to assume that every language has "methods" and "classes".